# How to pass text from cell to textView in another View Controller?

Tags: swift

I have an array of Strings - [notes]. There are two Views: Notes and NoteDetails. I want it to show note text in NoteDetails ViewController when user presses cell.

I was trying to do this with segue in didSelectRow tableView method, but xCode gives me an error:

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value".

```
var notes = ["one", "two", "three"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NoteDetailsViewController") as! NoteDetailsViewController
    vc.NoteDetailsOutlet.text = notes[indexPath.row]
    self.show(vc, sender: self)
}
```

If I type `po notes[indexPath.row]` in debug console, it shows me right result.

Comment: You're using forcing unwrap when instantiating the `NoteDetailsViewController`. You should check whether the identifier matches in storyboard and if so, if it's custom class is really `NoteDetailsViewController`.

Comment: Such a common mistake that I've now written a blog post about it! http://www.programmingios.net/dont-touch-my-outlets/ Thanks for inspiring me to write this up at long last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass text here create a variable in your `NoteDetailsViewController`

```
var passedNote: String = ""
```

Then use it here

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

      let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NoteDetailsViewController") as! NoteDetailsViewController
      vc.passedNote = notes[indexPath.row]
      self.show(vc, sender: self)

}
```

Check it in your viewDidLoad method that you got passed data or not

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(passedNote) // check here you will get data or not then add it to textView
    NoteDetailsOutlet.text = passedNote
}
```

**ExtraNote**: Following the naming conventions for variables should start with small letter such as `noteDetailsOutlet` instead of `NoteDetailsOutlet`.