# How to pass data from a TableViewCell to a ContainerView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new in using Swift and need help to pass data from a TableViewCell to a ContainerView to change some text of Labels.

My current status is to passing data from a TabelViewCell to a ViewController to change the text of a Label (IBOutlet) into a second ViewController with a segue.

But I don't know how to pass data from a Cell to a ContainerView with my own ViewController.

Here is a picture of my project

Here you can find the picture of my project and problem

[image: Here you can find the picture of my project and problem]

I just want to pass data from a TableViewCell of my "View_1" to "View_2" and change the text of the Label "Change_Text_1" in the ViewController "View_In_Container" of my ContainerView (UIView).

Perhaps you guys can help me with my problem. Thank you.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090195/how-to-pass-text-from-cell-to-textview-in-another-view-controller/56090650#56090650

Comment: Don't pass data from the **view** (cell), pass data always from the **model** (data source array). And please use *lowerCamelCased* variable names rather than *Upper_Snake_Cased*.

Comment: @vadian will make it better next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a `ContainerView` in `View_2` a child view controller(`View_in_container`) and a `segue` to the child view controller are added in the storyboard. Add an `identifier` to the `segue` and pass data from `View_2` `prepareForSegue` method. The segue from `View_2` to `View_in_container` is performed when View_2 is loaded

```
class View1: UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toView2", let view2 = segue.destination as? View2 {
            view2.name = "name"//Pass data from tableview data source array
        }
    }
}
class View2: UIViewController {
    var name:String?
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toChildVC", let viewInContainer = segue.destination as? ViewInContainer {
            viewInContainer.name = self.name
        }
    }
}
class ViewInContainer: UIViewController {
    var name:String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label1.text = name
    }
}
```

Select the segue from `View_2` to `View_in_container` and add an identifier `toChildVC`

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot. It works with your solution absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going with segue to other view controller you can pass data there, first add an identifier to the segue then in `prepare(for segue:...` you will have access to `segue.destination as? View_2`, then do the same with container and pass the value